# iPhone App connection with server for downloading content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am so sorry if I am asking a very silly question.

I am designing an app which will have short stories - some of them will be pre-installed with the app and others(free or paid) can be downloaded from my server. So I am planning to create an API on my web server which can cater to download/buying request from my app.

The problem is I am little confused how do I authenticate that the requests which my web server api are getting are genuinely coming from my app and by real users but not from some competitor or program who wants to grabs all my data and built his own app on top of it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to learn server side programming to develop such an app. But besides that, I must tell you that Apple won't approve your app if people will use your app to purchase contents like books, music, and news. And you can't have your own method of charging the user. All purchases to download/unlock content must go through the App Store, which means in-app-purchase is the only way.

Comment: Yes I will use in-app-purchase only, but I was not aware that even downloads of content should happen through App Store only

Comment: I didn't say that. But it's true that no new book selling apps will be approved.

Comment: After I read your first comment I started going through the in-app-purchase WWDC 2011 video and found that in-app-purchase only cater e-commerce content delivery I developer's responsibility. Ok so my question remains how do I authenticate or be sure of that I am delivering free content to genuine users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Store Kit API gives you a receipt when the user makes an in-app purchase. You send that receipt to your server. Your server can then verify the receipt with Apple to make sure the receipt is valid.

See [Verifying Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) in the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).